# Windows: How do I give Local System Account write access to a Shared Remote Folder (SMB) in a workgroup?

Tags: windows

So I am running a service (Jenkins) that is trying to write to a folder on another machine, but it fails with apparently a permission error. A normal user can write to the shared folder just fine. People say to give the Local System Account write access to the remote share, however, I don't see how to do that in a workgroup.  The remote share is on Windows Server 2008, however there is no domain controller.

Comment: Which version of Windows is trying to write to the share?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit is trying to write.